# Cannot install kube-prometheus-stack in k8s 1.15

Tags: kubernetes, alert, monitoring

Running kubernetes 1.15 in azure.

I need a basic alert (e-mail/slack notification) when one or more of my applications/pods are down in kubernetes.

As an example I have https://cert-manager.io/docs/ running in multiple clusters (hosted in azure) and I would like to get an alert (e-mail/slack notification) if it stops running.

Based on this post:

[How do I set up a hook to send an email on Kubernetes pod restart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691394/how-do-i-set-up-a-hook-to-send-an-email-on-kubernetes-pod-restart)

it seems to get an e-mail alert I need to install Prometheus + Grafana access the web-ui and configure alerts so based on:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack

I have tried:

```
helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.2", GitCommit:"d878d4d45863e42fd5cff6743294a11d28a9abce", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}


helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm repo update

helm install kube-prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace monitoring
```

But that gives:

```
Error: failed to install CRD crds/crd-alertmanager.yaml: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"
```

Here there is some guide on how to create the crds manually:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#helm-fails-to-create-crds

but that should only be necessary if running helm 2.x which I am not I am running 3.1.2.

Also if I try to install them manually I get:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.42/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagers.yaml
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.42/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagers.yaml": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.42/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_podmonitors.yaml
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.42/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_podmonitors.yaml": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.42/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_prometheuses.yaml
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/release-0.42/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_prometheuses.yaml": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"
...
```

Also I found this **kube-prometheus stack** compatibility matrix:

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus#compatibility

but versions in that matris does not match the ones I get:

```
$ helm search repo prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --versions
NAME                                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  10.1.2          0.42.1      kube-prometheus-stack collects Kubernetes manif...
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  10.1.1          0.42.1      kube-prometheus-stack collects Kubernetes manif...
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  10.1.0          0.42.1      kube-prometheus-stack collects Kubernetes manif...
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  10.0.2          0.42.1      kube-prometheus-stack collects Kubernetes manif...
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  10.0.1          0.42.1      kube-prometheus-stack collects Kubernetes manif...
```

So seems that might be a 3rd way to install Prometheus

Any input appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Randomly selecting the previous major version (9.4.10) seems to work:

```
$ helm install kube-prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace monitoring --version 9.4.10
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:192: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
NAME: kube-prometheus-stack
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Oct 23 15:15:03 2020
NAMESPACE: monitoring
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
kube-prometheus-stack has been installed. Check its status by running:
  kubectl --namespace monitoring get pods -l "release=kube-prometheus-stack"

Visit https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus for instructions on how to create & configure Alertmanager and Prometheus instances using the Operator.
```

Guess trial and error is the way to go when installing stuff on older k8s version, could be great with compatibility matrices though.

Comment: thank you so much. your answer helped me with EKS 1.14 and helm3.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the kube-prometheus-stack repo, this helm chart is restricted for K8s versions 1.16.0 or above;

> kubeVersion: ">=1.16.0-0"

Even though the github README says the prerequisites as `Kubernetes 1.10+ with Beta APIs`, internally the helm chart checks for the kube version to be 1.16.0 or above.

So I believe, you will need to try this on an upgrade K8s cluster.

If upgrading the cluster is not an option, maybe you could try the deprecated old version of this.

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus

Comment: Deprecated older version may match - I added the link to answer above.

Comment: Ah, that's also good given that the latest version is expecting 1.16 or above. Someone has down voted the answer, maybe they can give a reason as a comment when doing such.

Comment: Deprecated version worked for me. Just a heads up, instead of using helm install stable/prometheus use helm install prometheus-community/prometheus as the charts have been moved.